# Sharing a dmg file without recipient having to do xattr -d

Tags: macos, dmg, xattr

I've made a dmg out of my java project and when I try sharing it, the recipient gets "This application is damaged, move it to the bin". To get around this, xattr -d com.apple.quarantine on the command line can be used on the dmg and the following .app, but I would like to be able to have the user just click and open this without having to use the command line.

Comment: I haven't tried this but I suspect if you had a shared Dropbox folder with the other person and you put the `dmg` in your Dropbox and they ran it, it may work.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I just tried it and unfortunately, it didn't work. :/

Comment: I guess we'll have to wait for someone clever to come along and enlighten us :-(

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think making a pkg instead of a dmg makes it possibly work. Unsure yet, need to test more.

Comment: Did they download it from Dropbox via a browser, or do they have the Dropbox app installed on their Mac, and let that sync it? Browsers mark downloaded files as quarantined (which causes the signature check), but Dropbox sync doesn't.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for clarifying that - it didn't occur to me that anyone might use a browser to "download" from Dropbox :-)